# How to hide item from collection depending on some field value?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com, soft-delete

I override (custom operation and service) the DELETE operation of my app to avoid deleting data from DB. What I do is I update a field value: `isDeleted === true`.

Here is my controller :

```
class ConferenceDeleteAction extends BaseAction
{
    public function __invoke(EntityService $entityService, Conference $data)
    {
        $entityService->markAsDeleted($data, Conference::class);
    }

...
```

My service :

```
class EntityService extends BaseService
{
    public function markAsDeleted(ApiBaseEntity $data, string $className)
    {
        /**
         * @var ApiBaseEntity $entity
         */
        $entity = $this->em->getRepository($className)
            ->findOneBy(["id" => $data->getId()]);
        if ($entity === null || $entity->getDeleted()) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Unable to find this resource.');
        }

        $entity->setDeleted(true);
        if ($this->dataPersister->supports($entity)) {
            $this->dataPersister->persist($entity);
        } else {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('An error occurs. Please do try later.');
        }
    }

}
```

How can I hide the "deleted" items from collection on GET verb (filter them from the result so that they aren't visible) ?

Here is my operation for GET verb, I don't know how to handle this :

```
class ConferenceListAction extends BaseAction
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request, $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something; I'm not sure it's a best pratice.

Since when we do :

```
return $data;
```

in our controller, API Platform has already fetch data and fill $data with.
So I decided to add my logic before the return; like :

```
    public function __invoke(Request $request, $data)
    {
        $cleanDatas = [];
        /**
         * @var Conference $conf
         */
        foreach ($data as $conf) {
            if (!$conf->getDeleted()) {
                $cleanDatas[] = $conf;
            }
        }

        return $cleanDatas;
    }
```

So now I only have undeleted items. Feel free to let me know if there is something better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Custom controllers are discouraged in [the docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/). You are using Doctrine ORM so you can use a Custom Doctrine ORM Extension:

```
// api/src/Doctrine/ConferenceCollectionExtension.php

namespace App\Doctrine;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Extension\QueryCollectionExtensionInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;
use App\Entity\Conference;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;

final class CarCollectionExtension implements QueryCollectionExtensionInterface
{
    public function applyToCollection(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null): void
    {
        if ($resourceClass != Conference::class) return;

         $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
         $queryBuilder->andWhere("$rootAlias.isDeleted = false OR $rootAlias.isDeleted IS NULL);
    }
}
```

This will automatically be combined with any filters, sorting and pagination of collection operations with method GET.

You can make this Extension specific to an operation by adding to the if statement something like:

```
|| $operationName == 'conference_list'
```

If you're not using the autoconfiguration, you have to register the custom extension:

```
# api/config/services.yaml
services:

    # ...

    'App\Doctrine\ConferenceCollectionExtension':
        tags:
            - { name: api_platform.doctrine.orm.query_extension.collection }
```

If you also want to add a criterium for item operations, see [the docs on Extensions](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/#custom-doctrine-orm-extension)