# Symfony - modify DQL with doctrine extension for softdeleted entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I'm using `Symfony5` with `ApiPlatform`

I'm using `softdeleteable` on an entity `User`

Now when I delete a `User` :

- `ROLE_ADMIN` can't see the deleted users
- `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` can see every users, even the deleted ones

I just want to precise that my entity does have a `deletedAt` field and the softdelete work properly

To do so, I implemented a DoctrineExtension on this entity as such :

```
final class UserExtension implements QueryCollectionExtensionInterface, QueryItemExtensionInterface
{
    /** @var Security $security */
    private Security $security;

    /** @var EntityManagerInterface $entityManager */
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;

    /** @var AccessDecisionManagerInterface $accessDecisionManager */
    private AccessDecisionManagerInterface $accessDecisionManager;

    public function __construct(
        Security $security,
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        AccessDecisionManagerInterface $accessDecisionManager
    )
    {
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->accessDecisionManager = $accessDecisionManager;
    }

    public function applyToCollection(
        QueryBuilder $queryBuilder,
        QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator,
        string $resourceClass,
        string $operationName = null)
    {
        $this->addWhere($queryBuilder, $resourceClass);
    }

    public function applyToItem(
        QueryBuilder $queryBuilder,
        QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator,
        string $resourceClass,
        array $identifiers,
        string $operationName = null,
        array $context = [])
    {
        $this->addWhere($queryBuilder, $resourceClass);
    }

    private function addWhere(
        QueryBuilder $queryBuilder,
        string $resourceClass
    ): void
    {
        $token = $this->security->getToken();

        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->security->getUser();

        if (User::class != $resourceClass ||
            is_null($user) ||
            !$this->accessDecisionManager->decide($token, [GenericRoles::ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN])
        ) { return; }

        $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];

        $queryBuilder->andWhere("$rootAlias.deletedAt != 'null'");
    }
}
```

But I receive a `500` with the following error :

`" Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: \"null\"\nLINE 1: ...IS NULL) WHERE (d0_.id = $1 AND d0_.deleted_at <> 'null') AN...\n`

As if the query was trying to compare the `null` value to the timestamp field `deletedAt`

Does anyone see why the DQL query tries to do that ?

Thanks for your feedback !

Comment: Maybe it's the root alias (d). The docs on [Custom Doctrine ORM Extension](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/#custom-doctrine-orm-extension) show how to retrieve the actual root alias from the QueryBuilder and use it in a DQL expression. Also see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60801773/how-to-hide-item-from-collection-depending-on-some-field-value)

Comment: I've actually hit another problem not linked to this issue anymore.

You're comment helped me get passed this error though, so thanks a lot !